# Creating Textures for Sold Colour Models

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to create models in the 'low poly' style of the following image.
[image: example image]
What is the best way of texturing them?  My main questions are as follows.

To get a similar matt colour as shown in the example, can I just use a flat colour, or do I also need some kind of material?

Are flat colours immune to stretching and scaling issues?  Or would I have to handle it the same as a normal texture.

Does resolution matter when using flat colours, or would it look the same even if the texture was literally one pixel for each colour?

Am I better of doing this by creating the texture in a seperate program, or using something like vertex paint within Blender?

I'm only just getting into texturing, so simple answers appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create what is in the pictures you should not have to "texture." What you should do is assign different colored plain *Diffuse BSDF* materials to different parts of the mesh, as described [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=n-ZC155hC7Q). Last note: while the tutorial uses **BR**, use **Cycles** for a more similar-to-the-photo result.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell there are no textures in that image, just models with different diffuse colors asigned to the faces. This will help you out:

[Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Also, to answer your questions, flat colors do not get affected by scaling, they don't use resolution, and you don't need anything more than blender to create the material.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the materials in your example are just using a simple diffuse shader with no actual texturing occurring. If this is the case, then a simple diffuse shader material applied per face should do the trick.

A simple diffuse shader material should not have stretching or scaling issues, the resolution should not matter too much.